# increment and decrement operator with division and multiplication

Tags: java

```
public class Increment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = --a + a++ + ++a * ++b;

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

I cant understand why c == -1, please explain.

Comment: There are a lot of examples on SO explaining the increment and decrement operations in different scenarios. Please look at them instead. Adding another complex scenario question is unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: Please don't do weird things with operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You evaluate the unary operators from left to right. Then the multiplication is evaluated before the additions.

```
int c=--a   +  a++   +  ++a   *  ++b;
       -1   +   -1   +   (1   *   1)    =  -2 + (1 * 1) = -1
      a==-1    a==0     a==1    b==1
```